# How to solve this Stream Close exception error?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I am getting an error when try to parse data from front-end to back-end, getting this Stream close error when the line goes to the second one. I am seding the info thru post method with redux-saga.

```
def maquinasComProgramacoes = (JSON.parse(request.getReader()) as Map).entity as ArrayList
Boolean possuiProgramacoesSalvas = (JSON.parse(request.getReader()) as Map).possuiProgramacoesSalvas
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could read incoming data only once

```
def json = JSON.parse(request.getReader())
def maquinasComProgramacoes = json.entity as ArrayList
Boolean possuiProgramacoesSalvas = json.possuiProgramacoesSalvas
```

Comment: tks it worked like should be